# Is it fine to use "throw exception" inside parallel region?

Tags: c++, openmp

Will it be fine to use "Throw exception" inside the parallel region?

What will happen to rest of the threads when one thread throws an exception?

code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     if(arr[i] < 0)
       throw BadParameter("bad array value");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A throw executed inside a parallel region must cause execution to resume within the same parallel region, and it must be caught by the same thread that threw the exception.

Otherwise it will propagate into unhandled exception.

Comment: This is correct, but annoying. Is this ever going to overcome (in next openmp version)? I use a helper class to throw exceptions and it won't throw (but exit with a fatal error), if inside a parallel region *and* an object of type `ThrowGuard` exists.

Comment: @Walter, what would you expect the correct behaviour of future OpenMP to be in that case?